# Please explain FQL profile table pic_crop

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, profile

What do the coordinates returned by querying pic_crop mean when related to a profile picture. I have tried working this one out by cannot figure it!

Please help!

The values for left, top, right and bottom are a decimal like e.g. left 0.20115. What does 0.20115 mean? If you look at the source code for a facebook profile you will see that facebook is using a percentage to offset the profile photo. How does 0.20115 translate to facebook source of style="left:-23.13%;"

Answer (score 4):

Looking at a few examples of `pic_crop` from my friends' profiles, it seems like the left, right, top, bottom figures are percentages of the picture's total width. For example, my profile picture returns the following values:

```
    "width": 180, 
    "height": 161, 
    "left": 0.11466, 
    "top": 0.06897, 
    "right": 0.88534, 
    "bottom": 0.93103
```

Inspecting the Facebook timeline, the profile picture is shown square at 160px. Facebook doesn't crop the photo to show it, rather they scale it to fit the cropped area behind a 160px square window and then position the photo under that window to allow the cropped photo to show.

The "top" and "bottom" values of top: 0.6897 and bottom: 0.93103 seem to equate to "no vertical crop". I can see this on my photo and several other friends' photos. So, 0.93193 - 0.06897 = 0.86206 means that 100% of the height of the photo is used. (The same values work for left and right when there is no horizontal crop.)

There is a horizontal crop on my photo. For the left and right figures on my photo, the formula seems to be: (right - left) ÷ (0.93103-0.06897). For my photo this works out to 0.89400. So, 160 × 180 / 161 = 179px × 0.89400 = 160px. I tried this on a few other friends' photos, and this works. Replacing "right - left" with "top - bottom" also seems to work for photos with a vertical crop.

On my Facebook timeline, my cover photo img tag is styled `left:-5.93%;`. I've got equal amounts of left and right crop, so this should be 9.5px on a side. 9.5 / 160 = 5.93%.

I haven't unraveled the scaling for asymetrical crops yet.

Gotta love it when Facebook makes it easy for you like this!

**UPDATE**

Just read tonight's [developer's blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/22/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/) and there is an alternate method for getting cropped profile photos: The `profile_pic` table.

```
SELECT url, real_width, real_height FROM profile_pic
WHERE id = me()
  AND width=160
  AND height=160
```

The returned `url` has a profile photo scaled according to your specified `width` and `height` and is cropped, more or less, to the profile owner's intent.

Answer (score -1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/profile/:

> pic_crop: An object containing: uri: The URL to the largest-sized square profile picture for the object being queried. width, height: the pixel dimensions of this picture. **left, top, right, bottom: the pixel co-ordinates of the user selected crop for this profile picture.**

Now what about that is possibly unclear?

Comment: The values for left, top, right and bottom are a decimal like e.g. left  0.20115. What does 0.20115 mean? If you look at the source code for a facebook profile you will see that facebook is using a percentage to offset the profile photo. How does 0.20115 translate to facebook source of style="left:-23.13%;"