# Problems getting pic_crop with Facebook fql request

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to get `pic_crop` from my profile picture with the Facebook *fql* query:

```
SELECT pic_crop from profile where id=me()
```

And I am getting this back:

```
    "uri": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/XXXX, 
    "width": 320, 
    "height": 320, 
    "left": 0, 
    "top": 0, 
    "right": 1, 
    "bottom": 1
```

If I try to get the same for my friend's I get the same response: `0,0,1,1` which represents the full picture and therefor is completely useless.

Has Facebook changed something because I remember getting real values for *pic_crop*, like these ones:

```
"uri": "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/XXXX, 
"width": 320, 
"height": 320, 
"left": 0.11466, 
"top": 0.06897, 
"right": 0.88534, 
"bottom": 0.93103
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12037446/please-explain-fql-profile-table-pic-crop

Comment: Nope, it's not a duplicate, that post only explains pic_crop info. But    in my case a I'm getting no valid response.

Answer (score 2):

FB seems to only return the new large cropped image if the user changed his/her profile picture after this update.

EDIT:
the img returned by

```
https://graph.facebook.com/".$userid."/profile?fields=pic_crop,name"
```

will be large and cropped but the image returned by

```
https://graph.facebook.com/'.$userid.'/picture?type=large
```

will not be large and cropped if the user hasn't updated his/her profile picture recently

(Thanks Facebook for making our life easier)

ps: this is my first post here, I know this is not an answer but I couldn't find a respond button.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs (highlighted by me):

> pic_crop: An object containing: uri: The URL to **the largest-sized square profile picture** for the object being queried. width, height: the pixel dimensions of this picture. left, top, right, bottom: the pixel co-ordinates of the user selected crop **for this profile picture**.

It looks like Facebook creates a square image for the cropped version of the profile picture now – check the URL that you get from `pic_crop.uri`, it’s a square picture no matter what your actually uploaded profile picture looks like. (Compare `pic_crop.uri` to `pic` from the same table to see the difference.)

And since *this* version of the picture always seems to be square now, they will most likely have dropped the crop coordinates – “dropped” as in still delivering them so not to break apps relying on these properties being presents, but with values actually meaning “no crop at all”.

Comment: Seems you're right. I was trying to get a high resolution profile picture but which I would manually crop to the correct position and size. So it seems that is not possible anymore? But I see the crop information is encoded in the returned url itself. "http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/hprofile-ak-prn1/c5.20.679.679/s320x320/XXXXXXXXXXXXX_n.jpg" so 5,20 is the upper left coordinate and 679,679 is the bottom right. Is that documented anywhere or is it completely unreliable to use?